# VM Creation Fails with "Resource CREATE failed"

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

I just tried to create my first VM on the Bluemix VM beta. I selected Ubuntu 14 and took all the defaults for the VM. I uploaded an ssh key that I generated with PUTTYgen. Bluemix seemed to take it just fine.

But after I clicked the "Create" button, it churns for several minutes and then comes back with:

Your VMs are in error - Resource CREATE failed: Error: Resource CREATE failed: Error: Resource CREATE failed: ResourceInError: Went to status ERROR due to "Message: No valid host was found. , Code: 500"

The VM instance is listed in the web UI, but it's listed as "in error" and I can't do anything with it other than delete it.

Anyone seen this before? The only thing I supplied was a name and an SSH key, so it's difficult to imagine I screwed something up.

Anyone know if this is a transient error condition, or if it's permamnent? Is it worth trying to create a VM with user ID/pw access instead of SSH?

Comment: Creating a VM works now for me

Answer (score 0):

Yep I just got the same error-- contacted a developer who told me the virtual machines service is having issues at the moment and they're working to fix it. I can comment on your post when it's back up.

Edit: it works now

Comment: Yep. The support people got back to me and it was a temporary issue on their end. It was fixed and I was able to create a VM on Friday afternoon.